# What is the default value of an element in an array?

Tags: arrays, c, scope, initialization, cs50

I am currently taking the CS50x couse by Harvard and ran across the following problem.

In the short excerpt below, is hashtable[i] set to null by default? I am under the impression that when I allocate enough memory for 10 nodes (as in below), I should get 10 different addresses rather than null pointers. However, the course I am taking seem to suggest that even though I am allocating enough memory for 10 nodes, they won't be assigned addresses immediately. Instead, they will be assigned null pointers.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[N + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

node *hashtable[10];
```

Comment: You get ten *distinct* addresses, as in, ten spaces where an address can be stored. But they can still have the same *value*, i.e., point to the same thing (or to the same lack-of-thing, i.e., all be null).

Comment: Of course, the address value stored in a pointer can also just be invalid garbage. But no matter what, of course the pointers won't point at nodes yet because *there aren't any nodes yet for them to point at*.

Comment: Anyway, *what does the textbook say about this*?

Comment: How/if it gets initialized depends on where it is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the elements of the array

```
node *hashtable[10];
```

will be initialized by a null pointer or not depending on where the array is declared.

If the array has automatic storage duration that is if it is declared in a code block within a function then its elements are not initialized and have indeterminate values.

If the array is declared in a file scope (outside any function) then it has  static storage duration and its elements are initialized by a null pointer.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
> or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> ...

> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
> according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

Comment: A pointer with static storage duration and no initializer is initialized to a null pointer, not a null pointer constant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil From the C Standard  "If a null pointer constant is converted to a
pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer"

Comment: That says a converted null pointer constant is a null pointer. It does not say a null pointer is a null pointer constant, converted or not.

Comment: The relevant part of the standard would be C17 6.7.9/10 "if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;". Also see [What's the difference between null pointers and NULL?](https://software.codidact.com/q/278657)

Comment: The C standard permits C implementations to have multiple representations of null pointers. A *null pointer constant* is a particular expression in source code. The representation that a compiler uses to initialize pointers without explicit initializers is not necessarily the same one it uses for null pointer constants.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the hashtable array depends on where and how it is declared. If *hashtable* is declared outside of a function, each element is initialized to NULL (which essentially points to nothing). This is also true if *hashtable* is declared inside a function and has the storage class *static*. The only difference between the two is that the latter can only be accessed inside the function.

```
node *hashtable[10]; /*each element is initialized to NULL*/

void f(void)
{
    static node *hashtable[10]; /*each element is initialized to NULL*/
    ...
}
```

If *hashtable* is declared inside a function and does not have the storage class static (i.e. is a regular local variable), each element is undefined which in practice means that it could have any value:

```
void g(void)
{
    node *hashtable[10]; /*each element is undefined*/
    ...
}
```

The reason for this difference is that variables which exist during the whole lifetime of the program can be initialized for free by the compiler; the variable is compiled into the executable. On the other hand, initializing a local (non-static) variable needs to be performed each time a function is called and is therefor associated with a run-time cost.